# Propagating errors and rolling back transactions that span procedure calls?

Tags: sqlite, tcl

My question concerns catching errors and rolling back database transactions when the transaction spans a few levels of procedures calls.

I wrote the code, first, just to get it working and used a lot of `if [catch {db eval {...}} result catchDict]` statements for all the database code; and then attempted to wrap it in a transaction.

It became necessary to re-throw the errors that were caught and I tried code like

```
if [catch {db eval {...}} result catchDict] {
  dict incr catchDict -level 2
  return -options $catchDict $result
}
```

which appeared to work in terms of propagating the errors up to the calling procedure. However, it did not work with `db transaction {...}` but I may have done something wrong, of course. I tried

```
if [catch {db transaction immediate {::DOCS::AppendToUndoChain $request}} result catchDict] {
puts "rolling back"
puts $result
puts $catchDict
}
```

which stopped execution in `AppendToUndoChain` at the point of error but did not roll back database changes performed within procedures called/invoked by `AppendToUndoChain` or a procedure under that.

The following seems to work fine and rolls back everything regardless of which level of procedure call the query was performed.

```
db eval {begin immediate;}
if [catch {::DOCS::AppendToUndoChain $request} result catchDict] {
 db eval {rollback;}
 puts "Rolled back."
 puts $result
} else {
  db eval {commit;}
}
```

**Question 1:** Am I doing something wrong with the `db transaction {...}` or the re-throwing of errors such that it won't roll back across all procedures?

**Question 2:** Is a `catch` on every `db eval {...}` really needed or can the one around the call to `::DOCS::AppendToUndoChain` take care of it all, such that all errors in that procedure and any procedure "below" it will propagate "up" to this `catch` and handle the errors and roll back of the transaction, such that all the queries can be coded as `set result [db eval {...}]` rather than `if [catch {db eval {...}} result]`?

I've tried introducing different types of errors in procedures at different levels relative to this single/outer `catch` and it appears to catch them all and roll back the complete transaction; but I'd like to know if this is a sound approach and what I might be overlooking.

Thank you for considering my question.

Comment: As far as I know, as long as you don't modify the schema, `transaction` works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catching and rethrowing exceptions transparently is a little more subtle than you might expect (or than the documentation makes clear): the cases `break` / `continue` / `return`; `error`; and `ok` are all a little different in terms of the fiddles needed to rethrow them transparently:

```
proc my_transaction script {
    set rollback 0
    # start transaction
    try {
        uplevel 1 $script
    } on return {r o} - on break {r o} - on continue {r o} {
        dict incr o -level 1
        return -options $o $r
    } on error {r o} {
        set rollback 1
        return -options $o $r
    } on ok r {
        return $r
    } finally {
        if {$rollback} {
            # do rollback
        } else {
            # do commit
        }
    }
}
```

This is what (in effect) sqlite is doing on the c level with its `db transaction {...}` command, with the small addition of keeping track of the transaction nesting and calling `ROLLBACK TO _tcl_transaction ; RELEASE _tcl_transaction` or `RELEASE _tcl_transaction` if nested instead of `ROLLBACK` and `COMMIT` respectively.  But if you want to do similar (that is: run some code in a section and do some non-db commit / rollback actions based on its exception status, then rethrow the exception so that the outer `db transaction` does the right thing, then you'll need to use a similar construction.

How that looks will depend on your use case (it's not quite clear from your question).  If you're doing a bunch of things that must happen atomically on the db level, and just report an error if something fails then the idiom would be something like:

```
try {
    db transaction {
        foreach client $clients {
            set name [dict get $client name]
            db eval {insert into clients (name) values (:name)}
            foreach addr [dict get $client addresses] {
                db eval {insert into addresses (client, addr) values (:client, :addr)}
            }
        }
    }
    puts "will only be reached if no exception was thrown"
} on error {errmsg options} {
    puts stderr "Error doing things: [dict get $options -errorinfo]"
} on ok {} {
    puts "Things went fine"
}
```

Nice and simple: either all the client addresses are loaded, or none are, if the code loading them throws an error (exactly code `TCL_ERROR` - anything else: `TCL_BREAK`, `TCL_CONTINUE`, etc are all treated as success by sqlite's `db transaction` and will trigger a commit).

But if the code *within* the `db transaction` needs to do its own exception handling with rethrowing of exceptions you'll need something like:

```
proc with_logo {logovar client script} {
    upvar 1 $logovar logo
    set old [pwd]
    set tmpdir [file tempdir]
    try {
        cd $tmpdir
        set logo client_logo[expr {int(rand()*1000)}].png
        exec curl -o $logo [dict get $client logo_url]
        uplevel 1 $script
    } on break {r o} - on continue {r o} {
        dict incr o -level 1
        return -options $o $r
    } on return {r o} {
        dict incr o -level 1
        dict set o -code return
        return -options $o $r
    } finally {
        cd $old
        file delete -force $tmpdir
    }
}

try {
    db transaction {
        foreach client $clients {
            with_logo fn $client {
                set logo_md5 [exec md5sum $fn]
                set logo_size [file size $fn]
                if {$logo_size == 0} {
                    puts "client [dict get $client name]'s logo is empty"
                    continue    ;# skip clients with broken logos
                }
            }
            set name [dict get $client name]
            db eval {insert into clients (name, logo_md5, logo_size) values (:name, :logo_md5, :logo_size)}
            foreach addr [dict get $client addresses] {
                db eval {insert into addresses (client, addr) values (:client, :addr)}
            }
        }
    }
    puts "will only be reached if no exception was thrown"
} on error {errmsg options} {
    puts stderr "Error doing things: [dict get $options -errorinfo]"
} on ok {} {
    puts "Things went fine"
}
```

Just an aside: be careful of code like: `if [catch {foo}] {...}`: the first arg of `if` is an expression.  Written like this it will take the result of the `catch` command and *reparse* it as a Tcl expression (a different language) with another round of substitutions, which is difficult to reason about and a rich source of remote code execution security vulnerabilities.  For this reason I strongly advise always brace-quoting expressions (like `expr {$a + $b}` rather than `expr $a + $b`, or, like this case, the expression args of `if`, `while`, `for`, etc.  In this exact case it's safe, but for fragile reasons: the return value of `catch` will always be an integer, whose string representation can never be interpreted as something that will trigger additional dangerous substitutions during the expr parse round.

Comment: It's best to not do too much with developing complex control constructs without writing a decent number of tests first. You can get 99% of the way there easily enough, but 100% can be tricky. (I find it is getting the stack trace right that is the most annoying part.) I find it is much easier to get things right with `try` than fiddling around with `catch`.

Comment: Yes, in all the places I've done that it I've drawn the line at fiddling with the stack traces.  I agree with you on the importance of tests - it's full of opportunity for subtle problems, but once you get it right it's a really nice pattern, that I've built whole extensions around: https://github.com/cyanogilvie/chantricks.  But your comment reminded me to be paranoid, so I just added tests for that to chantricks, which fortunately seems ok :)  My initial answer was wrong for the return handling though, so I accept your point ;)

Comment: I didn't realize that the conditions to an `if` could be a `$varName`. I should've, of course, and knew there is a variation of `switch` that works similarly depending upon the `{`s. Regading `if`, for example, `set x 5; set y {$x < 10}; if $y {...}` and it doesn't test the value of $y but substitutes it and evaluates the expression. Same for `expr $y`. Different from `if {$y} and expr {$y}` Maybe I just get stupid bouncing around between coding languages but it seems that Tcl can do interesting things more easily than some other languages and also makes it easy (for me) to make mistakes.

Comment: I see the `if [catch {...}] {}` style in a lot of old code, and iirc even some books.  AOLserver's internal Tcl code was full of it.  For a fun mental exercise, consider a web request handler containing `if [form_val show_details] {...show the details...}` when given `&show_details=%5Bsocket%20-server%20%7Bapply%20%7B%7Bc%20args%7D%20%7Bfconfigure%20$c%20-buffering%20none;while%20%7B!%5Beof%20$c%5D%7D%20%7Bputs%20$c%20%5Btry%20%5Bgets%20$c%5D%20on%20error%20m%20%7Bset%20m%7D%5D%7D;close%20$c%7D%7D%7D%2012345;list%201%5D`, assmuing `form_val foo` returns the decoded value of the param `foo`